# IOS Modal View Controller Presents Black Screen

Tags: core-data

I am working on an IOS app and have been stumped by this problem for about a week now and cannot find a solution.  Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.  Here's my set-up:

1. I have a tab bar controller.
2. I have a TableViewController which has a navigation bar with a navigation item "Add".
3. After you press the "Add" selector I am modally presenting another viewController that has a picker on it.
4. I am using Core Data.

When the second view controller is modally presented it comes up with a black screen with a navigation bar.  If I access the second view controller from an unrelated screen modally it comes up fine without the navigation bar.

No error message is logged, not even that the object wasn't saved when you press the "save" on the navigation bar.  However, pressing "save" will bring you back to the TableViewController and it looks like the entity was added.

Here is the code in my TableViewController:

```
- (void)add:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *addController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    addController.delegate = self;

    Entity *newEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    addController.entity = newEntity;

    UINavigationController *navController =  [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addController];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}

- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)secondViewController didAddEntity:(Entity *)entity {

    if (entity) {        

    [self showEntity:entity animated:NO];
}

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)showEntity:(Entity *)entity animated:(BOOL)animated {
    EntityDetailTableViewController *detailViewController = [[EntityDetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    detailViewController.entity = entity;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:animated];
}
```

Here is the code in my second View Controller:

```
- (void) save {

    entity.attribute = attributeTextField.text;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![entity.managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
        {
        NSLog(@"Problem saving attribute: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        NSLog(@"saveAttribute");

    [self.delegate secondViewController:self didAddEntity:entity];

}
```

Any suggestions on where to go from here would be really helpful.

Comment: I am facing similar issue on this sample project https://drive.google.com/open?id=1urYFRmhvxh4LPP9g78iMreEcVimSAsBo any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much frustration I found the answer.  If you are using storyboard you cannot navigate to the next view controller by the standard code.  I put the prepareForSegue statement in my TableViewController.m file and then hooked up the connection on storyboard and identified the segue.

Now, when you press the Add button it segues to the new view controller screen and it's not black.

[Here's a link to a useful tutorial](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-storyboards/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the way you are initializing is not right:

```
SecondViewController *addController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
```

should be `initWithNIB:`

Comment: When I try the initWithNib: I get an error message "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle'.  I think this is because I am using storyboard.

Comment: Update:  I tried adding another view controller that only had a textField on it and replaced it with the view controller that had the picker on it, and am still experiencing the same black screen.  Does anyone know of a different way to initialize a second view controller presented modally using Storyboard?  This seems to be the problem.

Comment: Just use a Segue in your storyboard, ctrl drag from whatever action triggers the modal to appear, like from a button or table cell to the modal view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've tried that and it does nothing.  I think the problem is in the line that initiates the SecondViewController.